# What are the control lines in the ATmega328P for?

Tags: avr, microprocessor, atmega328p

I'm trying to understand the block diagram for AVR architecture in the [datasheet for ATmega328P](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf#G1215228) on page 9. In it, I see that instruction decoder is connected to control lines. What are they in terms of microprocessor parts or function?

Also, there's the interrupt unit. Is that only for external interrupts like from an IO device or does it get involved even in software interrupts like timer/counter overflows?

Comment: The instruction is being decoded into specific signals which tell different components of the CPU what these need to do for this instruction (such as the operation type of ALU for example). These are the control signals. In a full diagram, these should be routed to aforementioned ALU and other components. This diagram is simplified.

Comment: "timer/counter overflows" are not "software interrupts". The timers (and other things like UARTs, etc) are all hardware modules which exert hardware interrupts to the interrupt controller just like an external interrupt pin would.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Would you like to add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yeah, the quality goes down here. People quickly post comments instead of actual answers, it's a pity. You might want to address them like this: @brhans.

Comment: @thebusybee I didn't post an answer because I didn't (and still don't) regard what I wrote as an answer to the question. I wrote a *comment* in order to correct a misunderstanding in the question. If you think that what I wrote does actually answer the question, then feel free to post it as an answer yourself.